# Optically detect specific characters in a text document

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, feature-detection

We try to detect certain rare characters when doing OCR of scans of old documents.

What is the state-of-the-art approach to text-object detection in document image analysis and OCR? Are standard SURF or SIFT algorithms applicable?